PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $2
I have the following SQL query case into JPA repository:
  @Modifying
  @Query(value = """
                    insert into tokens (
                           id,
                           ......
                           ) values (
                           :id,
                           ....
                           case when :arh is not null
                              then :arhToken else null
                           end,                                                  
                           ........
                           )                                                                 
            """, nativeQuery = true)
  void create(@Param("id") UUID id,
              @Param("arh") InternalToken ach,
              @Param("arhToken") String arhToken);

........

repository.create(
            UUID.fromString(token.getId())
            Optional.ofNullable(token.getArh()).orElse(null),  
 
Optional.ofNullable(token.getArh()).map(InternalToken::getArhToken).orElse(null)

);

When I run the code I get error
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $2

I need to make a check is the Object Arh empty of not into the case statement. What would be the best case to implement this?

In my view it would make more sense to convert the case logic to java layer and change nativeQuery to JPA query as InternalToken Object is not identified as a valid datatype in PostgreSQL level

Can you show me some code example, please?

Compute arhToken in the service layer -> String arhToken = Optional.ofNullable(token.getArh()) .map(InternalToken::getArhToken) .orElse(null);.
And call the updated repo without switch-case - repository.create(tokenId, ..., arhToken);. Also update Repository to JPA query INSERT INTO tokens(..., arhToken) VALUES(..., :arhToken)
